# VLOOKUP issue when comparing two columns that are not length

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a workbook in which i need to compare two columns and return a result. The fields used in the vlookup have the same format. When the vlookup was created, i provided a range, meaning the each value should look at the specified range. Would anyone have an thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: And what is the issue? VLOOKUP found nothing so you get N/A

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to use a drag-formula. Your ranges are changing every cell. Use the `$` character to prevent that from happening.

Something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A6,F$1:G$15,2,FALSE)
```